# How to use LINQ Group Records and use Distinct

Tags: c#, linq

given this Records

```
class Record
{
    DateTime Date {get; set;}
    string Article {get; set;}
    string Platform { get; set;}
    string Amount { get; set;}
}
```

With a sql query I get a list of Records and want to Group the Platforms by Article.

I do this query:

```
List<Record> recordList = FetchRecords();
var group = recordList.GroupBy(
    f => f.Article, 
    (key, g) => new 
    { 
        Article= key, 
        Platforms = g.Select(p => p.Platform).ToList() 
    });
```

There are around 120 different Articles and about 30 different platforms, so the expected amount of items in group is around 120 yet I am recieving thousands of items. Items in record list are a lot as its the stock of all articles in the last 30 Days so I want to get a distinct list of Articles. I just can't figure out where to do this. what am I missing?

**Edit**:

After further inspecting the Data at runtime I just noticed that I have it backwards. the Articles are already correctly grouped, the platforms are the ones that need to be distinct, like Astrid E was guessing in the comments

Comment: _Of what_ do you want to get a distinct list? Do you mean distinct `Platform` values for each `Article`?

Comment: Property `Article` is from type string, do you have constraints on input of this property (e.g Capital/Small letters) or it you set a const value inside it?

Comment: What are you using Entity Framework? Where does the list come from? It would be better if you showed some more code surrounding your problem. If you resolve the list before you do your grouping all rows will be fetched into memory.

Comment: @AstridE. Expected result is a list of distinct articles, each with all platforms that were related to this article.

Comment: @SomarZein the Article Property is filled from database, there is no user input. As mentioned in the question there are about 120 Articles

Comment: @PaulSinnema I get the recordList from a SQL Query which I parse into List<Record> wich is the recordList

Comment: I'm unable to quality check this at the moment, but does this bring you closer to your desired result? `Platforms = g.Select(p => p.Platform).Distinct().ToList()`

Comment: @AstridE. Yes, this is exactly what i was needing, thank you. if you post this as answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return distinct values of the `Platform` collection by using [`Enumerable.Distinct()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=net-6.0).

The `Platforms` value in the result selector in your `.GroupBy()` operation should be computed as follows:

```csharp
Platforms = g.Select(p => p.Platform).Distinct().ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try something like this:

```
var group = recordList.GroupBy(r => r.Article)
                      .Select(a =>
                        new
                        {
                            Article = a.Key,
                            Platforms = a.GroupBy(g => g.Platform)
                        });
```